# Can a subnet use more than one default gateway address?

Tags: router, subnet, default-gateway

This follows another question i had previously asked.. I am in a situation where sub net A is connected to two routers `{Router A{left}}` and `{routerB{right}}`. The `sub net A` knows that the address of the interface of `router A` is its default gateway but there is also `router B` which is also connected to `sub net A` but from the right.... How do we make `sub net A` have some kind of secondary default gateway address? Thank You

Comment: Most often, different gateways lead to different networks. So, you'd set up a *specific* route to each of these networks. Normally, there's only one *default* gateway (=fits all) but you can have multiple ones as Ron has explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The sub net A knows that the address of the interface of router A is its default gateway

Default routes are configured on hosts, not subnets.

It may be helpful to remember that a default route is just like any other route -- it just has the shortest mask.

If you want one route to be the "secondary" route, you first need a mechanism for determining that the primary route is no longer valid.  That can be the interface status or information learned from routing protocols.

You also need a methods to indicate the preference of one route over another.  there are usually two methods for this:  a *metric* for routes of the same type, and a *preference* for routes of a different type.

One route is preferred over another, and that's what the host uses to route packets.  If the preferred route is no longer preferred, the next best route is used.

Comment: Thanks for this info, where can i get tutorial on how to make a route prefered over another?

Comment: Should i configure it as a gateway of last resort?

Comment: A default route and gateway of last resort mean exactly the same thing

Comment: Route preference depends upon the device OS and the type of routing.

Comment: how do i make a router that is the default gateway of PC0,contact another router to ping a certain ip address?

Comment: Why should it ping another router?  Normally routers use a routing protocol to share routing information with other routers.

Comment: @DongLi Generally, more specific = longer prefixes are preferred over shorter, less specific ones. If there's a tie the lower metric/cost decides.

Comment: @Zac67, thanks for making that clear. I was just wondering what device is needed to make the local area network accessible to the web